# Data Partitioning and Replication on Cassandra cluster

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql, cassandra-3.0

I have a 3 node Cassandra cluster with RF=3. Now when I do `nodetool status` I get the **owns** for each node in the cluster as 100%.

But when I have 5 nodes in the cluster wit RF=3. The **owns** is 60%(approx as shown in image below).

Now as per my understanding the partitioner will calculate the hash corresponding to first replica node and the data will also be replicated as per the RF on the other nodes. 
Now we have a 5 node cluster and RF is 3.

Shouldn't 3 nodes be owning all the data evenly(100%) as partitioner will point to one node as per the partitoning strategy and then same data be replicated to remaining nodes which equals RF-1? It's like the data is getting evenly distributed among all the nodes(5) even though RF is 3.

[image]

**Edit1**:

As per my understanding the reason for 60%(approx) **owns** for each node is because the RF is 3. It means there will be 3 replicas for each row. It means there will be 300% data. Now there are 5 nodes in the cluster and partitioner will be using the default random hashing algorithm which will distribute the data evenly across all the nodes in the cluster.

**But now the issue is that we checked all the nodes of our cluster and all the nodes contain all the data even though the RF is 3.**

**Edit2**:

@Aaron I did as specified in the comment. I created a new cluster with 3 nodes.

[image]

I created a Keyspace "test" and set the class to simplestrategy and RF to 2.

[image]

Then I created a table "emp" having partition key (id,name).

[image]

Now I inserted a single row into the first node.

As per your explanation, It should only be in 2 nodes as RF=2.

But when I logged into all the 3 nodes, i could see the row replicated in all the nodes.

I think since the keyspace is getting replicated in all the nodes therefore, the data is also getting replicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Percent ownership is not affected (at all) by actual data being present.  You could add a new node to a single node cluster (RF=1) and it would *instantly* say 50% on each.

Percent ownership is purely about the percentage of token ranges which a node is responsible for.  When a node is added, the token ranges are recalculated, but data doesn't actually move until a streaming event happens.  Likewise, data isn't actually removed from its original node until `cleanup`.

For example, if you have a 3 node cluster with a RF of 3, each node will be at 100%.  Add one node (with RF=3), and percent ownership drops to about 75%.  Add a 5th node (again, keep RF=3) and ownership for each node correctly drops to about 3/5, or 60%.  Again, with a RF of 3 it's all about each node being responsible for a set of primary, secondary, and tertiary token ranges.

> the default random hashing algorithm which will distribute the data evenly across all the nodes in the cluster.

Actually, the distributed hash with Murmur3 partitioner will evenly distribute the token ranges, ***not*** the data.  That's an important distinction.  If you wrote all of your data to a single partition, I guarantee that you would *not* get even distribution of data.

Comment: Aron I got your point regarding the effective ownership(owns) that it is related to  token ranges evenly distributed across all the nodes. But I didn't understand how all the rows that I inserted in one node only got replicated across all the 5 nodes even though my RF is 3. As per my understanding it should have been on 3 nodes only. That is what RF tells us. But why I am able to see all the data across all the 5 node?

Comment: Also, could you please tell what do you mean by " If you wrote all of your data to a single partition, I guarantee that you would not get even distribution of data". What exactly is the partition?

Comment: @YugSingh how do you know 100% of your data is on each node?  Did you query and verify with tracing?  If it actually is, it could be because you have multiple logical racks specified.

Comment: If you wrote all of your data to the same partition key, your data would all be concentrated on 3 nodes, and 2 would be completely empty.

Comment: Aaron Thanks for the explanation. But I am getting more confused. As we specify the Replication factor and class while creating the Keypsace. Shouldn't the keyspace be accessible in nodes equal to RF specified? I think since the keyspace is accessible in all the nodes irrespective of RF, it means the table and it's data will also be replicated in all the nodes. I created the keyspace as mentioned in Edit2 section of the question.

Comment: Aaron I understood where I was going wrong. I did the trace on and found out that the number of nodes involved were indeed equal to replication factor.

Answer (score 1):

The data replicated to another nodes when you add them isn't cleared up automatically - you need to call `nodetool cleanup` on the "old" nodes after you add the new node into cluster. This will remove the ranges that were moved to other nodes.

Comment: Alex I called the ```nodetool cleanup``` command but the ```nodetool status``` still displays the same % under owns as mentioned in the question. But the owns is not confusing but the very fact that even though the keyspace RF is 3, all the 5 nodes of cluster has all the data. Shouldn't only 3 nodes be holding the data and remaining 2 should not. Could you explain this?

Comment: How did you check that node has data? By sending request to it?

Comment: I did the "cqlsh" into all the nodes and I can see the same data replicated in all the nodes irrespective of Replication factor. For example if I have 5 nodes and RF is 2. All of 5 nodes are having the same data.

Comment: In Cassandra you can send request to any node, and even if it doesn't own the given range, it will simply forward request to the node that "owns" that data. In this case, node is called "coordinator node"... I recommend to read https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/ - it gives good overview of the Cassandra architecture (with some DataStax specifics although)